# SQL Server query optimizer performing an unnecessary join

Tags: sql-server, join

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on why SQL Server (2016 RTM in my case, but I suspect this is not version-specific) is performing this seemingly unnecessary INNER JOIN.

Consider the following two tables joined by a foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[batches](
[Id] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
[Date] [date] NOT NULL,
[Run] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[Clean] [bit] NOT NULL) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[batch_values](
[Batch_Id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[Key] [int] NOT NULL,
[Value] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_batch_values] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [Batch_Id] ASC, [Key] ASC))
GO 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[batch_values]  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT  [FK_batch_values_batches] FOREIGN KEY([Batch_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[batches] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[batch_values] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_batch_values_batches]
GO
```

Populate the tables with some data:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
    @BatchCount int,
    @BatchId smallint,
    @KeyCount int;

SET @BatchCount = 1;

WHILE @BatchCount <= 100
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.[batches]
    VALUES (DATEADD(dd, @BatchCount / 10, '2016-01-01'), @BatchCount % 10, @BatchCount % 2);

    SET @BatchId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    SET @KeyCount = 1;

    WHILE @KeyCount <= 1000
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO dbo.batch_values
        VALUES (@BatchId, @KeyCount, RAND() * 1000000 - 500000);

        SET @KeyCount = @KeyCount + 1;

    END;

    SET @BatchCount = @BatchCount + 1;

END;
```

Now, if I run the following query the execution plan shows that the SQL Server is performing the INNER JOIN to the [batches] table, even though no columns are selected from it, and no records could be dropped from [batch_values] as a result of the join due to the foreign key constraint.

[screenshot of query and execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u14Rj.png)

It seems to me that Query Optimizer should discard the INNER JOIN as unnecessary and simply do a primary key seek on [batch_values], but it doesn't.

This is material because if I develop views that join multiple tables to present a "bigger picture" of the underlying data for ease of use, when querying those views I will be taking a performance hit.

Comment: Rows couldn't be dropped, but they could be multiplied.

Comment: Oh, no they couldn't, because you're specifying the PK on batch_values. Hmm.

Comment: Oh yes they could because a FK only goes one way. It could be missing from the other table. This is a strange case because it's a vertically partitioned table (both joining on the primary key). If I read the FK the correct way, you can create a record in `batch` without it existing in `batch_values` (but not the other way)

Comment: Hi Nick. Yes, you are reading the FK correctly, it is possible to have a batch in [batches] table but no corresponding values in the [batch_values] table. Semantically it would mean an empty batch, i.e. batch was generated but turned out to be empty. However, it is not possible to multiply records in the [batch_value] via a join with [batches], since [batches].[Id] is the primary key, so there could be only one.

Comment: It's not possible to multiply but it is possible to _exclude_. It's an inner join. I wonder if an outer join would operate differently

Comment: It's not possible to multiply because of the PK on [batches].[Id]
It's not possible to drop because of the [batch_values].[Batch_Id] to [batches].[Id] FK

Comment: You're right I got that FK backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many limitations to use JOIN ELIMINATION by SQL Optimizer

E.g. if you use multiple columns in the foreign key, or constraint is not trusted, or marked as 'not for replication', etc.

SQL Server may not use JOIN ELIMINATION if you specify WHERE predicate with the column in foreign key.

Remove WHERE or remove "Batch_id = 100" from WHERE, and you should see the Optimizer now uses JOIN ELIMINATION

The documentation is limited on this topic, so I can't provide a proof link, but many people reported this issue in the past 5-7 years for different versions and agreed that behaviour was by design. My recommendation is to raise an incident with MS and ask them directly about it if it is critical for your system.

Comment: I played around with it some more, as well as did some more searching for JOIN ELIMINATION, and looks like you are correct about the WHERE clause.